# Failed to download any source list - android SDK

Tags: android-sdk-tools, platform-tools

I'm trying to download platform-tools from Sdk Manager. but when I run

```java
C:\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\tools\bin>sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

the following warning errors are showing

```java
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
Warning: Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Warning: Failed to find package 'platform-tools'
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...
```

Im having java JDK 8
Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in my Linux machine, It has something to do with `.android` folder (Maybe due to previous installations) which is present in `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` path which usually is your user's folder. In Windows it is `C:\Users\<User>\.android` and in Linux it is `/home/<user>/.android`. After hit and trial, I have found that we can  do either of the following to solve the issue:

- Simply delete `.android` folder in the path

**OR**

- set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` path as another directory

and try to run the `sdkmanager` command again