# npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-studio

Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [37m 43s]

> IDLE

why i have the same phrase
my problem is repeat this same phrase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sdkmanager Warning: Failed to download any source lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714625/sdkmanager-warning-failed-to-download-any-source-lists)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.